# Runtime.freeMemory() and company or early allocation to prevent late out of memory errors

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I am writing a program which, depending on *JVM, heap size and user settings*, is likely to throw some `OOM` errors pretty often.

I do not want to give it some arbitrary limits, but since, when this errors are going to occur, the program will likely take a lot of time to run before producing some meaningfull output, I wanted it at least to quit as soon as possible if an `OOM` is going to happen. My first approach was to initialize the most memory consuming objects early, which probably is not a good practice.

Since some more memory can be needed later depending on user input, I also wanted to ensure some reasonably safe margin of free memory, and, after some awful ideas, I figured out that using methods from `Runtime` and giving the user some data  on the remaining memory, on what can be expected from that data and a warning if needed would be a more elegant solution.

One of the early initialized objects is an array used to write to an audio file, it is not used until the end of the program and I considered adding it's size to the free memory calculation and initializing it only when it is needed.

As far as I see the major flaws with calculating free memory before are the following:

1. It is not completely accurate
2. For some objects the actual size in heap memory cannot be predicted and depends on the implementation
3. In corner cases the program will still terminate at the end of the computation, when the objects are initialized, not as soon as there is not enough memory left to complete the program. Doing repeated checks can be a solution, but this can affect performance.

And the major problems with early initialization are the following:

1. It freezes some resources which aren't used, probably affecting performance.
2. May affect readability and maintainability of the code, especially if misused and/or in larger programs.
3. Causes the program to always exit with an error instead of preventing it and exiting in a graceful way.

What would be in most cases the best approach to this kind of problem, are there better solutions or other factors that should be considered or are some of the one I mentioned more or less important than I think?

> PS I probably can and should improve memory management and this would mitigate or almost solve the problem in most cases and caring about memory management should be the priority, but I think it is still a valid question. I understand that Runtime.freeMemory() cannot be used as it seems at a first glance .

EDIT

I'll try to clarify what I mean by early OOM.

Chunk of memory A (used from the beginning, reasonably predictable by options)

Chunk of memory B (variable, depending on user input)

Chunk of memory C (used at the end, reasonably predictable by options)

Normal way: A ,B ,long computetion, C (the OOM will likely happen here)

Early initialization: A ,C ,B (the OOM will likely happen here), long computation

One important point that I missed (and probably outweights the others in most real world programs) is that some memory from A and B will likely be freed before C is used and early initialization will cause the program to fail even when there's no need for it.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. How is the application supposed to know an OOM is going to happen *without* some sort of required memory precalculation?

Comment: In the other case the application doesn't know an OOM is going to happen, the OOM is just happening earlier, because the objects, at least the predictable ones, are created long before being used. Suggestion for other sorts of memory precalculation are also welcomed.

Comment: "I do not want to give it some arbitrary limits" : why would you give arbitrary limit? You should know how much memory your program needs + keep some wiggle room to account for difference between different JVMs. Attempt to predict when OOME is going to happen is hazardous and should be avoided.

Comment: How am I supposed to know how much memory my program needs if attempting to predict when an OOME is going to happen is hazardous and there's no reason to give it some arbitrary limits?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your program to quit quickly when `OutOfMemoryError` is thrown use `-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError` or `-XX:+CrashOnOutOfMemoryError` option. This will ensure that when OOME is thrown in your program the JVM will exit. See [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/outofmemoryerror-related-jvm-arguments) to understand the difference between these options.

Do note that `OutOfMemoryError` is thrown in few situations: not enough memory to allocate an object, GC overhead limit reached, file descriptor limit reached, etc.

Comment: I want the Error to be thrown earlier or the program to quit in another way if it's going to be thrown in the future, so that the user doesn't have to wait for a long computation without getting what the program is supposed to do. I'll see if I can make the question clearer.

Comment: @Harpistry there are ways to "listen" to the java heap, so when old generation (for `G1` let's say) is getting to a certain percentage, you could do whatever you want. But either way, I've read your question 3 times and still don't understand what you want to achieve. Pity, cause it seems it might be interesting.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do different things depending on the time the application goes out of memory, you can use [`Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler)).
The pre-shutdown logic will likely need some memory, which you need to allocate up-front and release when needed.

```
byte[] memory = new byte[4096];
final AtomicBoolean shuttingDown = new AtomicBoolean();

Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler((thread, throwable) -> {
    if (throwable instanceof OutOfMemoryError) {
        if (shuttingDown.getAndSet(true)) return; // Execute the following logic only once
        memory = null; // Release pre-allocated memory
        // Do pre-shutdown logic
        System.exit(0);
    }
});
```